# Draw arrow from node to nothing

Tags: mermaid

I want to draw a mermaid diagram containing arrows that do not join with nodes:

```
graph LR
    A(Sample Text)
    -->A
    A-->B
    B-->A 
    B-->
```

`-->A` and `B-->` fails, likely because the arrow requires both input and output nodes. Is there a workaround? Can I make the node invisible or blank?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about this?

```
graph LR
    START[ ]-->A[Sample Text]
    A-->B
    B-->A 
    B-->STOP[ ]
    
    style START fill:#FFFFFF00, stroke:#FFFFFF00;
    style STOP  fill:#FFFFFF00, stroke:#FFFFFF00;
```

**Output diagram is:**

[image: --> sample text <--> B -->]

Answer (score 18):

Simply tag the node with `:::hidden` to hide it:

```
graph LR
    START:::hidden --> A
    A --> B --> A 
    B --> END:::hidden

    classDef hidden display: none;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Something similar to another comment, but using opacity:

```
graph LR
    START[ ]-->A[Sample Text]
    A-->B
    B-->A 
    B-->STOP[ ]

    style START fill-opacity:0, stroke-opacity:0;
    style STOP  fill-opacity:0, stroke-opacity:0;
```

Comment: Using opacity is better because the solution is independent of the background color.

Answer (score 2):

Easier and better if you want to continue from your invisible point:

```
a --> end[ ]
style end height:0px;
```

Seems like sometime github rendering have problem with the above, in this case use:

```
style end height:1px;
style end width:1px;
```

Answer (score -1):

A more simple way which I found [here](http://graphviz.996277.n3.nabble.com/Is-there-a-way-to-do-this-td3699.html)

```
digraph {
    rankdir=LR;
    nowhere [style=invis,shape=point]
    nowhere -> on
    on -> off [label = "Push"]
    off -> on [label = "Push"]
}
```

Output is something like

[image: State diagram of a push button]

Comment: Wasn't the downvoter, but I think it's because the question references mermaid-js and your answer is for graphviz